# Is there a way to add my django-tenant schema name to MEDIA_ROOT?

Tags: django, geodjango

I have modified my Geonode project, which is a GeoDjango project, to enable multi-tenancy using django-tenants. I am currently not able to view my thumbnails due to broken routing...

How do I correctly route my generated thumbnails like this: http://d3.demo.com(current_tenant_domain_url)/uploaded/d3(tenant)/thumbs/document-8a72dc8c-0151-11eb-a488-1062e5032d68-thumb.png

The thubnail url that is currently generated is as follows: http://localhost:8000/uploaded/thumbs/document-fcdea3a4-015c-11eb-a488-1062e5032d68-thumb.png?v=c1855f6a

urls.py

```
  urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
    urlpatterns += static(settings.LOCAL_MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

My current settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.getenv('MEDIA_ROOT', os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, MEDIAFILES_LOCATION))

MEDIA_URL = os.getenv('MEDIA_URL', '%s/%s/%s/' % (FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME, MEDIAFILES_LOCATION, MULTITENANT_RELATIVE_MEDIA_ROOT))
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django_tenants.middleware.main.TenantMainMiddleware'
]

DATABASE_ROUTERS = (
    'django_tenants.routers.TenantSyncRouter',
)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'django_tenants.files.storages.TenantFileSystemStorage'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'public', 'media')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [...] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: [http://localhost:8000/media/thumbs/document-f645dbe6-0168-11eb-a488-1062e5032d68-thumb.png?v=9dc701b5] Not Found: is what I get could you elaborate on how to get the current domain instead of localhost and how to get the domain(d3) between media and thumbs in the URL

Comment: you must use domain per tenant